# How do I make a FAB transform into an action menu in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, floating-action-button, action-menu

I've seen multiple examples and projects that include a speed dial such as is found in Google's own Calendar app. But instead, I want to make a FAB transform into an action menu such as is demonstrated on [material.io](https://material.io/design/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html#types-of-transitions). They show [a graphic that demonstrates this](https://storage.googleapis.com/spec-host-backup/mio-design%2Fassets%2F1pdXG8K2i6IR9i5V5raflvDwuADXdUACM%2Ffab-transitions-menu-1.mp4), but as I've found have not documented anyway to do this in the Flutter API. Would anybody know how to accomplish this whether it be in a package or custom code (I am fairly adept at Flutter and Dart)?

Comment: Maybe you should have a look at: https://github.com/js94766524/fab_menu
It's not exactly what you're looking for but I think it may help you.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can achieve this by using showModalBottomSheet 
Give it a try :

```
 floatingActionButton: Builder(
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return FloatingActionButton(
                child: Icon(Icons.edit),
                    showModalBottomSheet(
                      context: context,
                      builder: (BuildContext context) {
                      return //widgets you want 
             });

          );
        })
```

Comment: Non-functional example.